# Over-matching with regular expression function re.findall() in Python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am using Python 2 and I have a string as follows.

```
s = """
f = function(x) sum(is.na(x))

apply(xdat, 2, f)

sum_it = function(xdat) {
    ans = apply(xdat, 2, sum)
    return(ans)
}
"""
```

I intend to extract the `sum_it` function that is enclosed by `{}`. I used the code below

```
print(re.findall(r"\s+[\w._]+ = function\(.+?\)\s*{.+?\n}\s", s, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])
```

which gives me the wrong result:

```
f = function(x) sum(is.na(x))

apply(xdat, 2, f)

sumit = function(xdat) {
    ans = apply(xdat, 2, sum)
    return(ans)
}
```

I made it explicitly clear that the substring I want should include `{}` in there. But why does this regular expression fail to exclude the beginning part of the string that clearly does not have `{}` in there? How can I get this:

```
sumit = function(xdat) {
    ans = apply(xdat, 2, sum)
    return(ans)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the wildcard match in the parentheses.  Since you're using "." to match the argument list, it can also match parentheses characters.  The first match includes everything between the first open paren and the last close paren.  If you change the line to this, it should work (although you get a lot of extra space at the start, and there are better ways to do this match):

```
print(re.findall(r"\s+[\w._]+ = function\([^)]*\)\s*{.+?\n}\s", s, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])
```

**Update after discussion:**

At first glance it would seem that the non-greedy qualifier would look for the matching substring with the fewest characters.  The way it really works, though, is that it seeks the *first* substring that can be a match, and then matches as few characters as possible within that.

Comment: Thanks! It does solve my problem. But I added the non-greedy qualifier `function\(.+?\)`, why `?` is not working for me?

Comment: hmm, you're right.  I misread that and now I'm not sure why the non-greedy qualifier didn't work.  I'll have to look into this some more

Comment: Ok, I know why.  It's a little confusing: greedy applies to how many characters to consume once matching has begun, but it does _not_ check over all potential matches for which one consumes the least characters.  So even though it is not greedy, it is still taking the _first_ match it finds.